# Avoiding relative require paths in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I prefer to import dependencies without lots of relative filesystem navigation like `../../../foo/bar`.

In the front-end I have traditionally used RequireJS to configure a default base path which enables "absolute" pathing e.g. `myapp/foo/bar`.

How can I achieve this in Node.js?

Comment: Wouldn't it work create your own wrapper to `require` in the index file?

Comment: Yeah that could work - good idea! But I wonder if there is something built-in (a configuration option, for example).

Comment: As far as I know - no. I have never seen it anywhere.

Comment: I have found this - there are multiple solutions, unfortunately none of them are "build-in". https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `require.main.require` which would always be the module path of the starting file. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module

This means, that when you run

`const x = require.main.require('some/file/path/y')`

It would require it based on the base path of your starting file (that was invoked , `node app.js` meaning the app.js file).

Other options include using `process.cwd()` to get the starting path of your app, but that would be depending on where you invoke your node process, not the location of the file. Meaning, `node app.js` would be different than of you would start it one level up, `node src/app.js`.

Comment: Thank you. I have found relative pathing to be error-prone and tough to maintain on the front-end (I find it difficult to parse lots of `../`. How do you avoid this kind of problem on the backend? Or is this a non-issue for you?

Comment: Never really had a problem with it, to be honest. Unless you move around files, the relative paths are static in node.js, since they are always relative to the file invoking the `require`. Not sure how requireJS load files in web context, but a script tag is always relative to the current HTML document, so if you are injecting a script tag to load a js file, it will not be relative to the js file doing the injection. Maybe that is where your problem stems from?

Comment: I have had use cases for the require.main.require though, but that was actually from a node-module that wanted to look for a configuration from the app root folder, which is a very specific use case (and probably discouraged most of the time).

Comment: In the initial stages of application development I find it quite a common requirement to move files. If a file brings in shared dependencies like `../../../shared/utils/foo` then every file breaks if the nesting position changes. If the paths are instead "absolute" then this problem does not occur. I guess this is the use case I am thinking of...

Comment: @BenAston yeah, sure but any half decent IDE usually fixes that as part of refactoring move, so personally I never have issues with that.

Comment: Also, IDEs usually will let you see the absolute path if you hover over the `require` path.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other answer, you can put this few lines in your main file:

```
(function (module) {
  let path = require('path')
  let __require = module.constructor.prototype.require
  let __cpath = __dirname

  module.constructor.prototype.require = function (str) {
    if (str.startsWith('package:')) {
      let package = str.substr(8)
      let p = path.resolve(__dirname, package)

      return __require(p)
    } else {
      return __require(str)
    }
  }
})(module)
```

It extends your `require` in such way:

- if path begins with `package:` (i.e. `package:src/foo/bar`) it translates it to `require('/absolute/path/to/your/app/src/foo/bar')`,
- if it doesn't start with `package:` then it behaves like a normal `require` would.

Comment: after your snippet, i got this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`